# Adding scrollbar to p-overlayPanel

Tags: css, scroll, primeng

I have `p-overlayPanel` which has inside a table that can be very big and apears on all the screen, how can I add scrollbar?

Thanks

```
<button pButton
        type="button"
        icon="pi pi-angle-down"
        (click)="op.toggle($event)"
        iconPos="left"
        label="גרסאות קודמות"
        [disabled]="!isShowVersionValid()"
        class="ui-button-rounded ui-button-secondary"></button>
<p-overlayPanel #op [showCloseIcon]="false" [style]="{'overflow':'visible', 'padding': 0 ,'border':'none'}">
  <p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="data">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
      <tr>
        <th class="ui-column-title thdesign" *ngFor="let col of columns">
          {{col.header}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data let-columns="columns" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" >
      <tr *ngIf="data.docVersionNumber < length">
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns ">
          <div *ngIf="!col.isAnchor && !col.isDate" class="colDesign">{{data[col.field]}}</div>
          <div *ngIf="col.isDate"  class="colDesign">{{ data[col.field] | date: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"}}</div>
          <div *ngIf="col.isAnchor && !col.isDate">
            <a class="anchor" href="{{templateUrl}}?{{splitCoimPath(data.coimId)}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
              {{data[col.field]}}
            </a>
          </div>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</p-overlayPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use overflow:scroll instead of visible :

`<p-overlayPanel #op [showCloseIcon]="false"  [style]=" {width:'650px','max-height':'550px', overflow:'scroll', 'padding': 0 ,'border':'none'}">`